# How to run an android application requiring the safetynet/[basic root check] check on a pc?

Tags: android-emulator, safety-net

### Background :

I just sent my phone for screen repairs, but now I’m trying to find out how to pass the payment confirmation on PayPal or my android‑based banking app in order to get it sent back to me. The problem is they both checks for safetynet once installed. Though on my rooted phone, the unmainted MagiskHide is enough to get them working.

## Problem :

There are many android virtual machines or solutions without emulations like waydroid. But if some of them allows to run Google Play services, none of them pass the safetynet check or have Magisk working on them.
**I’m meaning they behave as if they are rooted devices** even when the virtual machine is unmodified.

Comment: In my opinion the easier way would be to ask your friends if you could borrow an old unused Android phone. Passing safety-net on a regular phone can be problematic but on an emulator it is even harder.

Comment: @Robert their phones are really really old to the point of not being able to run the apps (the 2 I know use them as a call only phone). Or at least those I can reach by what remains of gasoline in my car. **It doesn’t have to be a rooted android virtual machine**.

Comment: Use PayPal in the browser on your PC?

Comment: @JohnDallman it requires to confirm the login with a fingerprint or code on the phone in my country. So meanwhile, no debit card, and no sepa/wire transfers.

Comment: If you have activate 2factor auth via app, then registering a new app should require the same security measures like authentication on the web site.

Comment: Also posted on Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1823702/356789

Comment: @Robert it just doesn’t and prompt me to open their proprietary android app. It can only be done on android or iOS.